# where the term of startup came from?

Tags: terminology, literature-search, business-school

I am finding literature about the term startup came from, which is referring to budding company. However, the info is scarce. Can anyone suggest to me, what the best website to find for terminology/etymology used by scholars? If applicable, it is good if there is a journal discussing about this

Comment: I disagree with the off-topic claim. On the contrary, this request is perfectly within the scope of the "reference-request" tag; hence I've submitted an edit request to simply correct the tags. Moreover, I find that the answer offered (check the Oxford English Dictionary) is an excellent addition of information to this site.

Comment: @Tripartio This is Academia SE, not English SE. What does "startup" have anything to do with Academia?

Comment: I am a business professor. Getting help to understand the origins of the idea of "startup" is absolutely an academic question in my domain, and one whose answer I would appreciate. Perhaps the question isn't so apparently relevant to non-business academics, but it is to me.

Comment: @Tripartio From your explanation, this question is about the contents of your research. That's exactly why it is off-topic on this site. Please note the "put on hold" reason above.

Comment: @Tripartio We actually have [Startups SE](https://startups.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @scaahu, on the contrary, this question seems to me to exactly match the purpose of the tag "reference-request", unless I misunderstand that tag. That is, one of the explicit valuable uses of this site is to ask for recommendations for references related to some academic topic. The only problem with the original question is that this new user was unaware of the correct tag to use, which is why I tried to help by editing with the correct tags. Could you please verify if I am mistaken (please look up other questions that have used that tag)?

Comment: @scaahu, I'm sure that this question would be appropriate on Startups SE, but I also think it is quite appropriate here. If the OP hadn't posted it, I wouldn't have learnt from the fabulous answer, which I can now apply to similar questions I often have for other academic topics.

Answer (score 3):

The *Oxford English Dictionary* has this definition:

> *orig. U.S.* A business or enterprise that is in the process of starting up, or that has just been established; a startup company, venture, etc.

[So, as I read it, their definition contains an etymology.]

They have earlier examples of the adjective, but for the noun, they have examples of "start up" from 1970 and "start-up" from 1986, but "startup" only from 2001.

Comment: The Oxford English Dictionary is probably the best source that exists for finding the first usage of any word in English.